# Recursive Elimination of Character Groups in a String in Python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, recursion, search

Given a string with a series of Rs and Gs, search for a way to eliminate them by groups. You can ONLY eliminate if characters are grouped (at least 2).

```
Example 1: RGRRRGGGRR 
  v           v        v
RGRRRGGGRR = RGGGGRR = RRR = {empty}, thus there is a possible solution.

Example 2: GGGRGRGRG
v
GGGRGRGRG = RGRGRG, can no longer find groups, thus there is NO possible solution.
```

I made an initial recursive function but it ends with no solution even though there is a possible solution.

```
def fn(string, start):
    l = len(string)
    if l-start > 0:
        counter, isPop = 0, False               
        if string[start] == 'R':
            while counter + start < l and string[counter + start] == 'R': counter+=1
            if counter > 1:          # If there is the same letter adjacent to the current letter being checked, it will pop this group.
                for i in range(counter):                 
                    string.pop(start)
                    isPop = True                         
            if not isPop and start+counter == l: return False         # Returns false if previous action did not pop and
            else: return fn(string, 0 if isPop else start+counter)    # Letter being checked is the last element (it means
                                                                      # that there are still elements in the string that can
        else:                                                         # no longer be grouped and eliminated.
            while counter + start < l and string[counter + start] == 'G': counter+=1
            if counter > 1:
                for i in range(counter):
                    string.pop(start)
                    isPop = True
            if not isPop and start+counter == len(string): return False
            else: return fn(string, 0 if isPop else start+counter)
        if string: return False
    else: return True
    

ways = []
string = input()
for j in range(len(string)):   # Iterates through every position in the list and calls the fn just to see if it is possible.
    if True in ways:           # If there is a possible solution, it breaks the loop and prints "possible"            
        break
    ways.append(fn(list(string), j))
if True in ways: print("Possible") 
else: print("Impossible")
```

Cases that my algo doesn't work (returns false but there is actually a way):

```
1. GGRRGRRRRGGGGRGRGG
         v                v               v         v         v       v
GGRRGRRRRGGGGRGRGG = GGRRGRRRRRGRGG = GGRRGGRGG = GGRRRGG = GGRRRGG = GGGG = {empty}

2. GRRRGRRRGRRRGRRRGR
         v                     v               v       v          v        v
GRRRGRRRGRRRGRRRGR = GRRRGRRRGGRRRGR = GRRRGRRRGGGR = GRRRGRRRR = GGRRRR = RRRR = {empty}
```

Comment: Would you prefer a solution without any imports?

Comment: Imports are fine, just looking for a fast approach. cdlane's approach is currently the fastest. I think ajax's continues to check every possible solution which slows his process, but so far both entries work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator. Additionally, applying `itertools.groupby` to produce groupings up front leads to a shorter solution:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
def get_groups(s, chain=[]):
   if not s:
      yield chain+[s]
   else:
      r = [list(b) for _, b in gb(s)]
      for i, a in enumerate(r):
        if len(a) > 1:
           t = ''.join(map(''.join, [*r[:i], *([] if i >= len(r) else r[i+1:])]))
           yield from get_groups(t, chain+[s])

cases = ['RGRRRGGGRR', 'GGGRGRGRG', 'GGRRGRRRRGGGGRGRGG', 'GRRRGRRRGRRRGRRRGR']
for case in cases:
   print(f'{case}: {any(get_groups(case))}')
```

Output:

```
RGRRRGGGRR: True
GGGRGRGRG: False
GGRRGRRRRGGGGRGRGG: True
GRRRGRRRGRRRGRRRGR: True
```

`get_groups` produces an empty list `[]` if there is no possible path whereby the input is completed reduced to an empty string by removing groupings, and a listing of all the possible paths to an empty string.

Comment: Is it possible to exit as soon as it finds one solution?

Comment: @muw Yes, please see my recent edit. `any` can be used in place of calling both `bool` and `list`

Comment: Works very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your primary issue with respect to debugging this code is your coding style.

Besides being messy, you have ambiguous `return` situations; your 'R' and 'G' parallel blocks aren't identical; you fail to update the array length variable after popping the array; you appear to start the recursion at the wrong index.

The best I could come up with cleaning up your code is the following that passes one more case but still fails one:

```
def fn(characters, start):
    length = len(characters)

    if length - start > 0:
        for character in ['R', 'G']:

            counter = 0
            isPop = False

            if characters[start] == character:
                while start+counter < length and characters[start+counter] == character:
                    counter += 1

                if counter > 1:
                    # If there is the same letter adjacent to the current
                    # letter being checked, it will pop this group.
                    for _ in range(counter):
                        characters.pop(start)
                        isPop = True
                        length -= 1  # we've shortened the array

                if not isPop and start+counter == length:
                    # Returns false if previous action did not pop and
                    # letter being checked is the last element (it means
                    # that there are still elements in characters that can
                    # no longer be grouped and eliminated.
                    return False
            
                return fn(characters, start if isPop else start+counter)

        if characters:
            return False

    return True
```

My own solution is akin to that of @Ajax1234 as far as `groupby` goes:

```
from itertools import groupby

def eliminate_groups(string):
    if not string:  # base case of recursion
        return True

    # "RGRRRGGGRR" -> ['R', 'G', 'RRR', 'GGG', 'RR']
    groups = [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(string)]

    for index, group in enumerate(groups):
        if len(group) < 2:
            continue

        reduced = groups[:index] + groups[index+1:]  # a deficient copy

        status = eliminate_groups(''.join(reduced))

        if status:  # one of the variants succeeded!
            return status

    return False  # all of the variants failed!

if __name__ == '__main__':

    strings = ["RGRRRGGGRR", "GGGRGRGRG", "GGRRGRRRRGGGGRGRGG", "GRRRGRRRGRRRGRRRGR"]

    for string in strings:
        print(string, eliminate_groups(string))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
RGRRRGGGRR True
GGGRGRGRG False
GGRRGRRRRGGGGRGRGG True
GRRRGRRRGRRRGRRRGR True
>
```

Comment: Apologies for my messy work, I think my algorithm's mistake is that it only eliminates starting from the left of the string to the right, which misses some possible solutions, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm also not yet familiar with groupby.